# In Gremlin, how can I use the SubgraphStrategy when submitting a script

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

I am issuing Gremlin queries to a AWS Neptune database as follows:

```
client = Client(f"wss://{self.host}:{self.port}/gremlin", "g")
client.submit("g.V()...")
```

This works fine and I get the expected results.

I would like to include a `SubgraphStrategy` when issuing these queries. (I'm using a `SubgraphStrategy` to ignore nodes marked as deleted.) I can do this when I build the query dynamically, like this:

```
g = traversal().withRemote(remoteConn).withStrategies(
    SubgraphStrategy(
        vertices=__.hasNot("is_deleted"), edges=__.hasNot("is_deleted")
    )
)
g.V()...
```

I cant figure out how to specify the subgraph strategy when issuing the query as a string. For example, I've tried this:

```
client = Client(f"wss://{self.host}:{self.port}/gremlin", "g")
client.submit('g.withStrategies(SubgraphStrategy.build().vertexProperties(hasNot("is_deleted")).V()...')
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Neptune doesn't allow for that Java syntax that uses `.build()` when creating strategies, but I think it will support the Groovy syntax that was i[ntroduced at TinkerPop 3.4.9](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_withstrategies_groovy_syntax):

```
g.withStrategies(ReadOnlyStrategy,
                 new SubgraphStrategy(vertexProperties: __.hasNot('endTime')))
```

Comment: I tried the following:
`client.submit("g.withStrategies(new SubgraphStrategy(vertexProperties: __.hasNot('is_deleted'))).V()..."`


It is failing after "g.withS":


`gremlin_python.driver.protocol.GremlinServerError: 499: {"detailedMessage":"Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 7, error message : token recognition error at: 'tra'","requestId":"61b87c66-60f9-4240-9c8f-586b24cc02da","code":"MalformedQueryException"}`

Comment: what version of Neptune were you using? fwiw, kelvin lawrence was able to give the syntax I supplied a try on Neptune for me and it worked for him.